# Monte Carlo Simulation - float' object is not callable

Tags: python, error-handling, montecarlo

Consider the following function that generates k Monte Carlo estimatives for an Integral with size n:

> def MCExponencial(k, n):
>
> ```
> sample=[]
> values=[]
> estimative=[]
> for j in range(k):
>     sample = [geradorExponencial(L, e1, e2) for i in range(n)] 
>     values=[(math.exp(-L*e1) - math.exp(-L*e2)) * f(sample[i], a1, a2, a3, b1, b2,  b3, c)/func_exponencial(sample[i], L) for i in range(n)]
>     estimative.append(mean(values))
>
> return mean(estimativa), estimative
> ```

In my program, I do

> n=10
>
> mean, estimative = MCExponencial(100, n)
>
> while p < 1/math.sqrt(100) * standardDeviation(estimative, mean):
>
> ```
>     n = n+10
>     mean, estimative = MCExponencial(100, n)
> ```

but I am getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MM\Desktop\Python\MonteCarlo.py", line 110, in 
    mean, estimative = MCExponencial(100, n)
  File "C:\Users\MM\Desktop\Python\MonteCarlo.py", line 60, in MCExponencial
    estimative.append(mean(values))
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Ps: The error occurs at the 'while' iteration.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You reused the name `mean` for the result of a computation, replacing the `mean` function you also needed. Name one of these things something else, or move the second code snippet into a function so its `mean` doesn't hide the global, or do something else to resolve the name conflict.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed that was the problem :)